# JPA CascadeType's won't work as I expected they will

Tags: java, spring, jpa, cascade

Hello dear StackOverflow Community,
I've been having a problem lately, where I wasn't able to just put the reference of an already saved object in it. I don't want to save or update the object, since these objects are pre inserted in our database.

So basically my situation works as following:
I have a parent, in this case it is an Intake and the object has a List of IntakeTimes, which are declared as remainingDoses. Makes sense, huh.

When using the CascadeType.MERGE on the remainingDoses, I'm actually able to save the ChildDisease Object (uppermost parent object that I'm actually saving), but if a saved ChildDisease with such an IntakeTime on his Intake object exists, I receive a "Duplicate entry 'X' for Key 'X'" error.

When using the CascadeType.PERSIST on the remainingDoses, I'm getting the "detached entity passed to persist: com.x.x.entity.IntakeTime"

My models look as following:

#### ChildDisease.java (uppermost parent)

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="child_disease")
public class ChildDisease extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn(name="child_Fk")
    private Child child;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="disease_Fk")
    private Disease disease;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, orphanRemoval = true, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "medication_decree_Fk")
    private MedicationDecree medicationDecree;
}
```

#### MedicationDecree.java (direct child of ChildDisease.java)

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class MedicationDecree extends BaseEntity {

    @Column
    private float consumptionAmount;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private MeasuringUnit measuringUnit;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="medication_Fk")
    private Medication medication;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Intake intake;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private List<IntakeTime> intakeTimes;
}
```

#### Intake.java (direct child of ChildDisease.java)

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Intake extends BaseEntity {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    public List<IntakeTime> remainingDoses;

    @Column
    public Date date;
}
```

I'm looking forward for any help or tips, thanks community.

Comment: Could you add the full code to reproduce for example for MERGE case showing how you have initalized all entities before saving?

Comment: It isn't clear what JPA methods you are using, persist or merge, with the various cascade type operations. It also isn't clear in this 4 entity type graph, which are new and which are existing, or why you have different cascade merge operations at different levels. ChildDisease->MedicationDecree-> Intake all use cascade persist, while MedicationDecree->IntakeTime and Intake-> IntakeTime use cascade merge. If you are only working with ChildDiseases that exist, merge will NOT pick up MedicationDecree. And if using persist, it won't pick up any referenced IntakeTime.

Comment: Sounds though that you are creating new parents that reference existing IntakeTime instances in the graph, and calling persist. You must look up those existing IntakeTime instances from the current EnityManager context, and use those references in the ChildDisease. Maybe persist ChildDisease before setting those references, and then fix/save the ChildDisease after. Just looking them up does not force updates to them

Comment: @pirho Hey, thanks for your quick answer. This is my full ChildDisease related code / respectively the classes I need for saving the entity. I've tried what @/shockwave showed me with the existsById, but this one didn't work either. By trying to fetch the specific data (as you can see in the ChildDiseaseService.java (comments)), I've came up the same result. 

My code: https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/zaferuloyu.kotlin

Comment: @Chris Hey, thanks for your answer. To be honest at this point, I was just arbitrarily trying CascadeType operations in hope that it'll work, because for me it feels like that no combination of the cascade type methods work here. I'm pretty sure this isn't the case. What I want to do is that I can save and update a ChildDisease using one API endpoint, which works for every other entity. I've tried to look them up (I think so), as you can see in my provided hastebin link. I've tried to call them through the repository so they will be in the context, but it didn't work as expected. (1/2)

Comment: @Chris I've also tried to set them to the entity, but this one didn't work aswell. (outcommented stuff)

Comment: Good start but to reproduce the problem there is a need also for all the mapper code and also real data. And in a [minimal form](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You might then see the problem by yourself.

Comment: @pirho Hey, thanks for your answer. I've added some necessary information to another hastebin. https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/agujakupul.cpp

When debugging a while I've figured out, that I am able to save my JSON-Data, when there's the specific IntakeTime id missing in the intermediate table "intake_remaining_doses" as a tupel. 

Means: if I want to save an entity, which contains the IntakeTime with ID "1" in the Intake.remainingDoses List and in this intermediate table already is an entry with the ID "1", he gives me the stack trace for the "Duplicate entry 'x' for 'x'".

Comment: Why are you calling existsById on paused in intakeTime.getId values - was that switched from a findbyId in your testing? They would need to be added to the collection and set in the collection, but you also have the MedicationDecree.intakeTimes collection you must check as well. But you've found the issue - you've mapped Intake-> IntakeTime as a OneToMany, and your table only allows one IntakeTime per Intake. You either need to correct the existing Intake that references the existing IntakeTime so that only one references it, or change the table/mapping to be a ManyToMany.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for your answer, I just realized that this probably was the problem. In the meantime I've did some workaround in front- & backend and managed to fix the problem. Maybe with not a such good solution as you just answered with, but still with functionality ;) Thanks for your encouragement

Answer (score 0):

Your error occurred because you've tried to save an entity which is already existing in the database (detached), but the default `JpaRepository` doesn't have a way of identifying if an entity is new or old, so it tries to create a new entity in the database.

You can fix this in multiple ways. One of it would be implementing the `Persistable` interface.
Basically you need to implement `Persistable` on your entity and provide `isNew()` and `getId()` methods, now you can use the logic that if the `id` field is already populated return `true` in `isNew()`.

```
public class Intake extends BaseEntity implements Persistable<UUID> {
   @Override
   public boolean isNew(){
      return this.getId() == null; // or any other logic with which you can identify if it's a new object or not 
   }
}
```

Refer: [Persistable SpringDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Persistable.html)

Comment: Thanks for your submitted answer, but it isn't working on my problem. I've tried it and implemented it in multiple entities. Duplicate entry 'X' for key 'X' is still remaining. Any other fix? You said, there are multiple ways to fix it, since I also think that implementing the Persistable interface isn't very consistent. I think the best way somehow is to fix it using correct cascading, but I tried with almost every cascade type in this case.